# How to update a single row in a LazyColumn?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I have an Android Jetpack Compose screen. I am showing a list of things that includes an image and some text on each row.
I have implemented LazyRow to do this.

[image]

I would like to add the following feature: when I click on any row, I show an additional text in the row. Another click will hide this additional text. So a click on a list row behaves like a toggle.

Is there a way to granularly update a specific row? I have a viewModel that backs the data for this composable. But if I force a refresh with the whole list with one row updated, it recomposes the image for all the rows which wasteful.

What is the recommended way to do this in compose? I can't find any way to update a single row of a lazyColumn.

Is there a way to cache the painter object so that it does not get recreated unncesserarily?
I am beginning to miss the good old RecyclerView!

```
 LazyColumn(modifier) {
    this.itemsIndexed(flags, key = {_, flagData -> "${flagData.countryName}:${flagData.group} "}) {index, flagData ->
        RenderFlagRow(index, flagData, onRowClicked)
        HorizontalDivider(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), thickness = 2.dp, color = Color.LightGray)
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be better if you can add some image to get some clear idea on what you kinds of behaviour you would like to achieve.

Comment: I think if you show your actual screen today and some code would help to increment whatever you're doing.

Comment: I have added a screenshot. What I want is that when I click on a row, I want number 1 to appear. The next click it should disappear. The next click it appears again. And so on. I don't want to update the whole list when I click.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one of the ways is just creating a conditional based on a trigger/saved value.

If the user clicks the DogItemButton, the box will expand in the row and show the extra information. But you can just show whatever you're thinking.

```
@Composable
fun DogItem(dog: Dog, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

// var expanded will be used to track whether the dog item is expanded.
   
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Card(modifier = modifier) {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .animateContentSize(
                    animationSpec = spring(
                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioLowBouncy,
                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMedium
                    )
                )
        ) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                DogIcon(dog.imageResourceId)
                DogInformation(dog.name, dog.age)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                DogItemButton(expanded = expanded, onClick = { expanded = !expanded })
            }
            if (expanded) {
                DogHobby(
                    dogHobby = dog.hobbies,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(
                        start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_medium),
                        top = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_small),
                        end = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_medium),
                        bottom = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_medium)
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Scaffold used with the lazyColumn.

```
Scaffold(
        topBar = { WoofTopAppBar() },
    ) { it ->
        LazyColumn(contentPadding = it) {
            items(dogs) {
                DogItem(
                    dog = it,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_small))
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If there are more items than can fit on the screen, then will the expanded state get lost when we scroll away from an expanded item and scroll back to it later?

Comment: @greenrobo Check state management on docs. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables